# Grails, how to find by a record by its foreign key

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have two domains that are a part of a one-to-many relations ship.  I was wondering how i can query the child for the parents FK?  bellow is the psuedo-code for parent/child

Parent:

```
    class AlumProfile    {
String firstName
String lastName
    static hasMany = [alumLanguage  : AlumLanguage]


static mapping = {
    cache true
    id generator: 'assigned'

    columns {
        firstName   type:'text'
        lastName    type:'text'
    }

    //
}
static constraints = {
    firstName   (nullable:true)
    lastName    (nullable:true)
    }

    }
```

Child:

```
 class AlumLanguage {
String name
String level

static belongsTo = [alumProfile:AlumProfile]
static mapping = {
    cache true

    columns {
        name type:'text'
        level type:'text'
    }
}
static constraints = {
    name(nullable:true)
    level(nullable:true)
}
  }
```

Although I do not explicitly create the FK, grails takes care of creating it the MySQL DB on its own.  But, when i want to query the child by the FK like this:

```
  if(AlumLanguage.findByNameAndAlumProfileId(language.'language'.toString(), 'jIi-hRi4cI')==null){
        //do something
 }
```

I get an error:  No property found for name [alumProfileId] for class [class mgr.AlumLanguage]

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

thanks
jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a [criteria](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html):

```
def c = AlumLanguage.createCriteria()
def languages = c.get {
    eq('name', 'whatever-language')
    alumProfile {
        eq('id', 'jIi-hRi4cI')
    }
}
```

Comment: this returns a list.  i need to have the AlumLanguages object returned, so that I can edit/delete instances of it

Comment: Updated. However, if you're going to do it that way, you probably want to declare AlumProfile.alumLanguage as a `Set` to enforce unique members.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  out of curiosity, what do you mean by "declare AlumProfile.alumLanguage as a Set"?   Thanks again!

Comment: @jason - Actually, just ignore that statement. I'm not sure what I was thinking. By default it's a Set, anyway, so you shouldn't have to worry about anything.