# How to retrieve domain object with criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Domain Model:

```
class Member {
static belongsTo = [login: Login]
```

I want to retrieve Member object, knowing id of login.
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959735/grails-how-to-find-by-a-record-by-its-foreign-key)
i try something like:

```
    def c = Member.createCriteria()
def mem = c.get {
login {
    eq('id', login)
}
```

But doesn't work. How  to retrieve object properly in Grails controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of possibilities to do that. For example, you can use

```
def login = Login.read(id)
def member = Member.findAllByLogin(login)
```

Or you should probably change your criteria by:

```
def c = Member.createCriteria()
def mem = c.list() {
    login {
        eq('id',id)
    }
}
```

Or you can use a Where query:

```
def yourLogin = Login.read(id)
def member = Member.where { login == yourLogin }
```

Of course, it depends of your needs.

Hope that helps